# Using summation to create a new variable

Tags: stata

I have data that look like this:

```
| Country | Year | Firm | Profit |
|---------|------|------|--------|
| A       | 1    | 1    | 10     |
| A       | 1    | 2    | 20     |
| A       | 1    | 3    | 30     |
| A       | 1    | 4    | 40     |
```

I want to create a new variable for each firm *i* that calculates the following:

[image]

For example, the value of the variable for firm `1` would be:

```
max(20 - 10, 0) + max(30 - 10, 0) + max(40 - 10, 0)
```

How can I do this in Stata by country and year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a direct solution to your problem (note the use of `dataex` for providing example data):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str1 Country float(Year Firm Profit)
"A" 1 1 10
"A" 1 2 20
"A" 1 3 30
"A" 1 4 40
end

generate Wanted = -Profit
bysort Country Year (Wanted): replace Wanted = sum(Profit) - _n * Profit 

list 

     +-----------------------------------------+
     | Country   Year   Firm   Profit   Wanted |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  1. |       A      1      4       40        0 |
  2. |       A      1      3       30       10 |
  3. |       A      1      2       20       30 |
  4. |       A      1      1       10       60 |
     +-----------------------------------------+
```

The logic behind it is the following:

[image]

Comment: Wow, so tidy. Why on the second line is Wanted in parentheses?

Comment: The parentheses have meaning and are not cosmetic. See any good explanation of the -by:- prefix.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: This was the first answer posted. It didn't avoid the pitfall of taking the OP's algebra literally and wanting to implement the calculation in terms of maxima within groups. But I realised after posting that there must be a much simpler way of doing it and @Romalpa Akzo got there, which is excellent. I undeleted this on request because it does show some machinery for looping over groups and implementing a calculation for each group with a customised Mata function.*

Here I write a Mata function to return the wanted result for a group and then loop over the groups to populate a pre-defined variable.

To test the code for a dataset with more than one group, I use `mpg` from Stata's `auto` toy dataset.

```
mata : 

void wanted (string scalar varname, string scalar usename, string scalar resultname) { 
    real scalar i 
    real colvector x, result, zero  
    result = x = st_data(., varname, usename) 
    zero = J(rows(x), 1, 0)     
    for(i = 1; i <= rows(x); i++) { 
        result[i] = sum(rowmax((x :- x[i], zero))) 
    } 
    st_store(., resultname, usename, result) 
} 

end         

sysuse auto, clear  

sort foreign rep78 mpg 
egen group = group(foreign rep78), label  
summarize group, meanonly 
local G = r(max) 

generate wanted = . 
generate touse = 0 

quietly forvalues g = 1 / `G' { 
    replace touse = group == `g' 
    mata : wanted("mpg", "touse", "wanted")  
}
```

How did that work out? Here are some results:

```
. list mpg wanted group if foreign, sepby(group) 

     +--------------------------+
     | mpg   wanted       group |
     |--------------------------|
 53. |  21        7   Foreign 3 |
 54. |  23        3   Foreign 3 |
 55. |  26        0   Foreign 3 |
     |--------------------------|
 56. |  21       35   Foreign 4 |
 57. |  23       19   Foreign 4 |
 58. |  23       19   Foreign 4 |
 59. |  24       13   Foreign 4 |
 60. |  25        8   Foreign 4 |
 61. |  25        8   Foreign 4 |
 62. |  25        8   Foreign 4 |
 63. |  28        2   Foreign 4 |
 64. |  30        0   Foreign 4 |
     |--------------------------|
 65. |  17       84   Foreign 5 |
 66. |  17       84   Foreign 5 |
 67. |  18       77   Foreign 5 |
 68. |  18       77   Foreign 5 |
 69. |  25       42   Foreign 5 |
 70. |  31       18   Foreign 5 |
 71. |  35        6   Foreign 5 |
 72. |  35        6   Foreign 5 |
 73. |  41        0   Foreign 5 |
     |--------------------------|
 74. |  14        .           . |
     +--------------------------+
```

So, how would that be applied to your data?

```
clear 
input str1 Country  Year  Firm  Profit 
     A        1     1     10     
     A        1     2     20     
     A        1     3     30     
     A        1     4     40     
end 

egen group = group(Country Year), label  
summarize group, meanonly 
local G = r(max) 
generate wanted = . 
generate touse = 0 

quietly forvalues g = 1/`G' { 
    replace touse = group == `g' 
    mata: wanted("Profit", "touse", "wanted")  
}
```

Results:

```
. list Firm Profit wanted, sepby(group)  

     +------------------------+
     | Firm   Profit   wanted |
     |------------------------|
  1. |    1       10       60 |
  2. |    2       20       30 |
  3. |    3       30       10 |
  4. |    4       40        0 |
     +------------------------+
```